# How to disable/override the enter key for autocomplete?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext

In Sublime Text 3, I want to disable the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to select an item from the autocomplete drop down, and only allow the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to do so.

I found this section in the inbuilt `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ]
},
```

It seems that if I remove this from the config that <kbd>enter</kbd> will not select an item in the drop down. Unfortunately it is not recommended to change this file, and only to override it in my `User` files. I don't think I actually can edit it without modifying the `.app` contents.

I tried to override it by removing different sections, and also remove everything except `"keys": ["enter"]`, but nothing seems to work.

How would I go about achieving this without modifying the inbuilt `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` and only the `User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**I have never used Sublime Text 3,** but I don't think the following has changed since Sublime Text 2.

What you want to achieve is actually a standard feature in Sublime Text. You just have to turn it on.

This line from your the code you quoted …

```
{ "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
```

… means "only execute the command if the setting called 'auto_complete_commit_on_tab' is set to false". So simply turn on that setting.

In Default/Preferences.sublime-settings:

```
// By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
// This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
// Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
// ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
```

Put `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true` in User/Preferences.sublime-settings. Both mentioned files can be accessed via the Preferences menu.

Comment: I *love* the description for this setting "it's better if this setting is true, but we're going to set it to false by default"

Comment: Sounds like it is because it takes time to get used to: "Enabling Commit on Tab is recommended, but it will take a short time to get used to." http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html

Comment: `tab` makes so much more sense than `enter` to me; took about 2 seconds to get used to.

Answer (score 11):

You can assign it to a non existent command. Try adding the following to `User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "noop", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

Granted if you install/write a plugin that has a command `noop` you will need to change this command.

**Edit**

Lydell's solution is better :) Forgot about that setting (though it is in the context so I should have known...). Guess my answer is a more generic "how to disable a keybinding".

Answer (score 1):

tried the solutions given above but they didn't work.
after some work this is what i came up with.

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "hide_auto_complete", "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\n"}
}
```